# Lock running from EF and not from Management studio?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures, transactions

I have a stored procedure for archiving some tables. It runs for ~30 minutes (first run, moving 20+ million records). If I start the script from management studio, I can run other querys and anything including the tables under archiving while it is running.

However, if I run the script from code (C#, EF) I can not get any results from the server, not even from management studio.
I think (hope) this must be some connection string tweak but don't know what I'm looking for. What is the difference between mmstudio and ef ExecuteSqlCommand?

The c# code that runs the stored procedure:

```
SqlParameter daysparam = new SqlParameter("@Day", days);
using (ReportsContext rcx = new ReportsContext())
   {
       rcx.Database.CommandTimeout = 60 * 40;
       rcx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("Archive @Day", daysparam);
   }
```

The connection string:

```
connectionString="data source=localhost\SQLSERVER2014;initial catalog=****_dev;persist security info=True;user id=sa;password=***;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework"
```

Comment: It depends on your transaction isolation level, try to change your EF isolation level to snapshot or readuncommited

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that the sp starts with
`SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;`
`SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY LOW;`

Btw, the same sp runs without problem from management studio.

Comment: try to use TransactionScope before your context and test it

Comment: TransactionScope doesn't help it gives the result. I've used the code 

`using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope(
                            TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, 
                            new TransactionOptions() { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted}))`

Comment: You might be able to find the difference using SQL Server Profiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to add TransactionalBehavior.DoNotEnsureTransaction as the first parameter of the ExecuteSqlCommand:

```
rcx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(TransactionalBehavior.DoNotEnsureTransaction, "Archive @Day", daysparam);
```

Answer (score 0):

@Perrier's answer will work, however it's preferred by many to avoid any use of the "ExecuteSqlCommand" method due to the associated risks of SQL injection.

In EF6 it is possible to override the default setting for transaction handling when executing functions and stored procedures as I quote from this [entityframework.net](https://entityframework.net/knowledge-base/41502640/entity-framework-6-handle-transaction-at-database-level) post titled "Entity Framework 6 Handle Transaction At Database Level".

In my db context constructor we added the following snippet to set the required behaviour:

```
public class myContext : DbContext
{
     public myContext()
     {
         ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ContextOptions.EnsureTransactionsForFunctionsAndCommands = false;
     }
}
```

Following the changes being made the SP completed successfully without exceptions, prior to this the SP execution in EF would throw a lock exception within 15 seconds every time.

Quoting the answer directly:

> In the application I simply created a base repository class as
> follows:
>
> ```
> public abstract class BaseEntityFrameworkNonTransactionRepository<T> where T : DbContext, new()
> {
>     protected T _context;
>
>     protected BaseEntityFrameworkNonTransactionRepository()
>     {
>         _context = new T();
>         ((IObjectContextAdapter)_context).ObjectContext.ContextOptions.EnsureTransactionsForFunctionsAndCommands = false;
>     }
> }
> ```